# Word VBA: Modifying words by looping ActiveDocument.Words creates an infinte loop

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to loop through a Word document word by word. I'm currently using the ActiveDocument.Words collection which seems pretty simple. But, there is a strange issue that if I change the content of one word, the internal pointer doesn't move to the next word but instead point's once more to the same word that just was modified. And in some cases this creates a situation where the routine get stuck in looping over a single word infinitely.

An example code:

```
Sub LoopWords()
    Dim wd As Range
    i = 0
    For Each wd In ActiveDocument.Words
        If wd.Text = "foo " Then
            wd.Text = wd.Text & "bar "
        End If

        'Prevent infinite loop:
        i = i + 1
        If i > 99 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wd
End Sub
```

So for example using this macro in a doc containing a phrase "There is some foo in here." results in "There is some foo bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar ..." and so on.

So why on earth does it behave like this?
How can I loop word by word and modify the text when necessary?

Comment: You're not supposed to modify anything within `for each` loop... those loops act like getters and they are supposed to return info/data...I am not sure that is the cause here though...

Answer (score 0):

Your Macro is replacing "foo" with "foo bar" and causing it to read "foo" as a new word over and over again.

Instead of:

```
wd.Text = wd.Text & "bar "
```

Try:

```
wd.InsertAfter "bar "
```